# implement bounded buffer (non-block between reader and writer, block among readers, block among writers)

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency

Implement a bounded queue

Read:
If queue is empty, wait till it can return a value with time out
If another thread is reading from the queue then wait till that thread is done
Remove the first element from the queue and return it
Do not block if a thread is writing into the queue

Write:
If queue is full, wait till one value is read with time out
If another thread is writing to the queue, wait till that thread is done
Write the element at the end of the queue
Do not block if a thread is reading from the queue

I'm not sure if my implementation is correct

```
using namespace std;

template <typename T, int N>
class BoundedBuffer {
private:
    std::array<T, N> buffer;
    int read_pos;
    int write_pos;

    std::mutex reader_mutex; //mutex for between readers
    std::mutex writer_mutex; //mutex for between writers

    std::mutex shared_mutex;
    std::condition_variable reader_queue;
    std::condition_variable writer_queue;
    int timeout; //timeout in millisecond


public:
    BoundedBuffer(const BoundedBuffer&) = delete;
    BoundedBuffer& operator=(const BoundedBuffer&) = delete;

    BoundedBuffer(int t) :
        read_pos(0),
        write_pos(0),
        timeout(t) {
    }

    inline bool empty() {
        return read_pos == write_pos;
    }

    inline bool full() {
        return write_pos >= read_pos + N;
    }

    bool put(const T& data) {
        unique_lock<mutex> writer_lock(writer_mutex);

        {
            unique_lock<mutex> shared_lock(shared_mutex);
            if (full()) { //buffer full
                if (writer_queue.wait_for(shared_lock, std::chrono::milliseconds(timeout)) ==
                    std::cv_status::timeout)
                    return false;
            }
        }

        buffer[write_pos%N] = data;
        write_pos++;
        reader_queue.notify_one();
        return true;
    }

    pair<T, bool> get() {
        unique_lock<mutex> reader_lock(reader_mutex);

        {
            unique_lock<mutex> shared_lock(shared_mutex);
            if (empty()) { //buffer empty
                if (reader_queue.wait_for(shared_lock, std::chrono::milliseconds(timeout)) ==
                    std::cv_status::timeout) {
                    T t;
                    return make_pair(t, false);
                }
            }
        }

        pair<T, bool> result = make_pair(buffer[read_pos%N], true);
        read_pos++;
        writer_queue.notify_one();
        return result;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a bug in my code :
In put() and get() method, it calls wait_for() and checks return value.
 
If it's timeout, then return false, else it assumes the waiting condition is met and the code continues to put/get data.
 
If wait_for() returns because of spurious wakeup, and at the time the condition isn't met :
 
not full for put() and not empty for() get,
 
then it will overwrite existing data or read wrong data.

The fix is to use predicate in wait_for(). It will ignore the spurious wakeup.

```
    bool put(const T& data) {
            unique_lock<mutex> writer_lock(writer_mutex);

            {
                    unique_lock<mutex> shared_lock(shared_mutex);
                    if (full()) { //buffer full
                            if (writer_queue.wait_for(shared_lock, std::chrono::milliseconds(timeout),
                                    [this]() { return !full(); }) == false) {
                                    return false;
                            }
                    }
            }

            buffer[write_pos%N] = data;
            write_pos++;
            reader_queue.notify_one();
            return true;
    }


    pair<T, bool> get(int i) {
            unique_lock<mutex> reader_lock(reader_mutex);
            cout << "i : " << i << endl;

            {
                    unique_lock<mutex> shared_lock(shared_mutex);
                    if (empty()) { //buffer empty
                            if (reader_queue.wait_for(shared_lock, std::chrono::milliseconds(timeout),
                                    [this]() { return !empty(); })==false) {
                                    T t;
                                    return make_pair(t, false);
                            }
                    }
            }

            pair<T, bool> result = make_pair(buffer[read_pos%N], true);
            read_pos++;
            writer_queue.notify_one();
            return result;
    }
```